# Funcion java para encontrar numeros

Tags: java, matemáticas

Estoy intentando escribir un programa para mostrar la lista de números capicúa primos de un número de cifras ingresado por el usuario (entre `2` y `15`). Yo ya tengo las funciones de capicúa y primo.

Pero el problema que tengo es cómo hacer la función para que introducido ese número de `2` a `15`, imprima los números.

Si la entrada es `2`, hago `(2/2)*10` y hasta el `99`, haciendo que imprima el `11` (único primo y capicúa de 2 cifras).

Pero no sé materializarlo en un bucle.

Comment: Hola. Fernando. Muéstranos tu avance (código). Para poder ayudarte en tus dudas o inconvenientes  respecto a este.

Comment: ¿El problema entonces es que no sabes cómo crear el bucle?

Comment: **OJO** No es lo mismo Java que Javascript. Cuidado con los edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para eso necesito una función que obtenga cada dígito. En el siguiente enlace, se puede ver una respuesta bastante buena.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612712/how-to-make-a-really-compact-getdigit-method

```
public static int obtener_digito(int numero, int posicion)
{
    return (numero/(int)Math.pow(10,posicion))%10;
}
```

Usando esa función, se puede ir comprobando uno por uno, de afuera hacia adentro para ver si son iguales los dígitos.

```
public static Boolean es_capicua(int numero)
{
    Boolean es_capicua_actual = true;
    int longitud=(int) Math.log10(numero);
    for (int i = 0; i <= longitud/2; i++)
    {
        int izquierda = obtener_digito(numero,i);
        int derecha = obtener_digito(numero,longitud-i);
        if( izquierda!=derecha )
        {
            es_capicua_actual = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return es_capicua_actual;
}
```

También se necesita una función para saber si un número es primo. Por suerte la encontré, chusmeando un poco por el sitio.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/funciones/info

El único problema es que está en C, pero lo convierto a Java.

```
public static Boolean es_primo(int numero)
{
    Boolean es_primo_actual = true;
    if(numero<2)
    {
        es_primo_actual = false;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int x=2; x*x<=numero; x++)
        {
            if( numero%x==0 ){es_primo_actual = false;break;}
        }
    }
    return es_primo_actual;
}
```

---

**Resolviendo el problema principal:**

En internet encontré cómo se hace para pedir datos por teclado. Se declara un escáner, luego se le requieren números al usuario, y por último se cierra el escáner.

http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com.ar/2012/08/java-scanner.html

```
System.out.print ("Ingrese un numero del 2 al 15:\n");
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = teclado.nextInt();
teclado.close();
```

También, cómo mostrar algo en pantalla.

https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/Java/Salida-De-Datos

```
System.out.print(i);
```

Entonces, se puede comprobar con un `if` si el número está entre el `2` y el `15`, de esta manera. Por último, comprobar que los números que se vayan a mostrar sean capicúas, primos, y que tengan cierta cantidad de cifras. Para eso uso `Math.pow`, para generar un número que sea potencia de `10`, es decir, nosotros usamos el sistema numérico decimal.

```
if(n>=2 & n<=15)
{
    int potencia_10_actual=(int) Math.pow(10,n-1);
    int potencia_10_siguiente=10*potencia_10_actual;
    for(int i=potencia_10_actual;i<potencia_10_siguiente;i++)
    {
        if( es_primo(i) && es_capicua(i) )
        {
            System.out.print (i+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @FernandoFernández Traté de buscarle en internet la solución a este problema, fijate ahora, edité la pregunta. De Java no conozco mucho, pero anteriormente programé en otros lenguajes parecidos, el codigo que puse debería funcionar bien.

Answer (score 0):

Basandome en tu comentario, como ya tienes un código para detectar si es primo y otro para saber si es capicúa, voy a centrarme en como hacer el rango para hacer el filtro, tal y como dices, que si introducen un 2 filtre los números de dos cifras, si introducen un 3 filtre los de tres, y así sucesivamente.

```
int numero = 2;//Aquí el número que quieras, por ejemplo un 2, sería el que introducirías por pantalla

if(numero >= 2 && numero <= 15){

    double empezar = Math.pow(10,numero); //Aquí empezará el bucle (10 para el 2, 100 para el 3, etc...)

    double acabar = Math.pow(10, numero) - 1; //Obtenemos 99, 999, 9999...

    for(int i = empezar; i <= acabar; i++){
        if((esCapicua(i) == true) && (esPrimo(i) == true)){
            System.out.println("El número " + i + "es capicua");
        }
    }
}
```