# Calcular y mostrar persistencia de un entero

Tags: c

Es algo de un proyecto y necesito añadirle esto:

Calcular y mostrar la persistencia de un número entero dado. La persistencia de un
número es la cantidad de veces que hay que multiplicar los dígitos de un número hasta que se convierta en un número de un solo dígito.

En lenguaje C

Comment: Que haz intentado hasta ahora? Codigo?

Answer (score 2):

Hace poco respondí algo parecido.

[Funcion java para encontrar numeros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30672/funcion-java-para-encontrar-numeros)

Es necesario tener una función que permita obtener los dígitos.

Función sacada de aquí.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29612719/3038554

```
#include <math.h>

int getDigit(int number, int k)
{
    return (number/(int)pow(10,k-1))%10;
}
```

Entonces ahora hay que hacer que, mientras que tenga más de un dígito, pase algo. Es decir, mientras sea mayor o igual a 10.

Nota: Copio algo parecido a lo que tenía en la pregunta del capicúa.

```
while(numero>=10)
{
    int acumular = 1; 
    int longitud = (int)log10(numero);
    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        acumular *= obtenerDigito(numero,i);
    }
    numero = acumular;
}
```

Esto funciona solo para enteros menores a 2 elevado a la 31, es decir, unos 2 mil millones, debido a la limitación de la arquitectura, es decir, pero creo que es más que suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

No programo en C, pero un ejemplo que funciona en java y puede ayudarte a portarlo es este (ejemplo para nº 294):

```
int num = 294;
int repeticiones = 0;

System.out.println("Nº inicial es: " + num);
while(num > 9){
    int producto = 1;
    while(num != 0){
        int unidades = num % 10;
        producto *= unidades;
        num = (num - unidades)/10;
    }

    repeticiones++;
    System.out.println("Producto " + repeticiones + "º es:" + producto);
    num = producto;
}

System.out.println("La persistencia es: " + repeticiones + ", la cifra final: " + num);
```

Nos da esta salida:

> Nº inicial es: 294
>   Producto 1º es:72
>   Producto 2º es:14
>   Producto 3º es:4
>   La persistencia es: 3, la cifra final: 4