# Determinar si el número es primo

Tags: java

Es necesario determinar si el número introducido por el usario es primo o no.

Este es lo que tengo, pero siempre da como resultado que no es primo.

```
public static void primeNumber(int num) {
    boolean prime = true; 
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (prime)
        View.input("The number is prime.");
    else
        View.input("The number isn't prime.");
}
```

Comment: Esta pregunta está respondida dentro de [otra con más casos](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30672/funcion-java-para-encontrar-numeros) por @ArtEze.

Comment: Realmente tu función funciona bien. ¿Cómo la estas ejecutando? Cambia el `View.input` por `System.out.println` y tu función da el resultado correcto. He copiado tu código aqui: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58e4f68ffe191640fd3b599fb49195c3

Comment: @Neon revisa el método que propongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace poco hubo [una respuesta de @ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/30673/13558) muy parecida aunque incluía más casos.

Esta fué la solución para el número primo:

```
public static Boolean esPrimo(int numero)
{
    Boolean esPrimoActual = true;
    if(numero<2)
    {
        esPrimoActual = false;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int x=2; x*x<=numero; x++)
        {
            if( numero%x==0 ){esPrimoActual = false;break;}
        }
    }
    return esPrimoActual;
}
```

Además, una que aportó @AlexisRodriguez debajo de estos comentarios (aunque fue borrado porque en manera de comentario no se entendía).

```
boolean primo = false;
int numero = 5;
int contador = 0;
for(int i = numero; i > 0; i--){
    if(numero % i == 0 ){
        contador++;
    }
}
if(contador == 2){
    primo = true;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, primo);
```

Answer (score 4):

La definición de número primo es **un numero que sólo puede dividirse por 1 y por sí mismo**.

Por lo tanto puedes usar este método:

```
boolean esPrimo(int n) {
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Puedes encontrar más métodos optimizados en este [articulo](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/) por Oscar Sanchez

Este es el método más eficiente descrito:

```
//Revisa si un numero entero es primo o no.
boolean isPrime(int n) {
    //revisa si n es multiplo de 2
    if (n%2==0) return false;
    //si no, solo revisa los impares
    for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo. Su código funciona perfectamente usando `System.out.println`. Creo que lo está ejecutando de manera errónea. Mira, ejecuta esto: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58e4f68ffe191640fd3b599fb49195c3 aquí: https://www.compilejava.net/

Comment: Además, si algún número es divisible por otro número y da resultado cero entonces significa que ya no es primo.

Comment: Es más eficiente poner la raíz cuadrada en vez de n. `for(int i=3;i*i<=Math.sqrt(n);i+=2) {`.