# No logro entender porque me cuenta como 0 el contador, pero a la hora de mostrar en pantalla si me lo cuenta como debe ser

Tags: java, números-primos

No logro entender porque me toma el contador como cero a la hora de hacer la operacion, pero a la hora de mostrar en pantalla si me cuenta como deberia

```
package numeroprim;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NumeroPrim {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int contador,I,cantidad, numero;
        double total, totalv;
        System.out.print("ingrese la cantidad de numeros que desea poner a prueba: ");
        cantidad = entrada.nextInt();
 
        contador = 0;
 
        for(I = 1; I <= cantidad; I++)
        {
            System.out.print("Ingresa un numero: ");
        numero = entrada.nextInt();
            if(numero % 1 == 0 && numero % numero == 0 && numero % 2 > 0)
            {
                contador++;
                
            }
            
            
        }
       total= contador/cantidad;
                totalv= total*100;
                System.out.print("De los "+cantidad+ " numeros, "+contador+" son primos, y en porcentaje representa el %"+totalv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que estas haciendo división de números de tipo entero, por lo que no vas a tener decimales en la respuesta y aque primer se realiza la división (sin decimales) y luego se asigna a la variable doble.

Una forma fácil de corregir este detalle es forzar a que la división se haga con el tipo de dato doble de la siguiente forma

```
total= (double)contador/cantidad;
```

Con eso solucionas tu problema.

Comment: La respueseta es correcta desde mi punto de vista, solo agregarle un par de comentarios para mejorar su código: Las dos primeras condiciones del IF son suprefluas ya que siempre son verdaderas.  Un número dividido entre 1, siempre da resto 0, y cuando divides el número por si mismo, te dará resto cero siempre. 
Por otro lado, la última condición no te asegura que el número es primo, solo que no es divisible sin resto. Los primos son números que solo son divisibles entre si mismos y entre 1. **ej: 125 % 2 te dará 1, pero 125 no es primo, es divisible por 5, 25, 125 y 1,**

Comment: Los siguientes son números primos:   2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19.... etc. Tu condición solo encuentra número IMPARES

Comment: Puedes mejorar tu programa a partir de esta respuesta, incluye la función y llámala dentro del IF:   https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34897/154013